# When and why will this function return something else

Tags: c++, stl

I am reading the CPP's STL code to figure out something. And I reach a function in vector header file, the function is :

```
static size_type __align_it(size_type __new_size) _NOEXCEPT

    {return __new_size + (__bits_per_word-1) & ~((size_type)__bits_per_word-1);};
```

size_type is size_t, and __bits_per_word is :

```
static const unsigned __bits_per_word = static_cast<unsigned>(sizeof(__storage_type) * CHAR_BIT);
```

My compiler is clang and the version is like clang-800.x.xx.

My question is , when and why will __align_it return something else than __new_size.

Comment: Why don't you write some sample code that passes various values to __align_it(), and displays what it gets back. It should be fairly obvious.

Comment: ok, looks like I forget that + will be done before & operator, so it's alignment. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return something different than `__new_size` when `__new_size` is not dividable by `__bits_per_word`. In other words this function is used to round the `__new_size` to nearest multiple of `__bits_per_word`.

This is very common function used to properly align structure members if not automatically determined by compiler. For example when we have `char` array but we still want to align it to the same address as `unsigned` field because of access optimization.